# Android Maven Could not resolve dependencies for configuration

Tags: java, android, git, maven, dependencies

I'm facing this problem currently. The project did't have any build problems previously. Only today when I was trying to build it gives this error.

> Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':Project'.
>
> > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':Project:classpath'.
> >     Could not download artifact 'org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:4.0@jar'
> >     Artifact 'org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:4.0@jar' not found.

Seems like `asm-analysis:4.0` is not found in maven repo. 
(Is this link correct? http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C1692005229)

Inside my build.gradle file, I've set the repository to `mavenCentral()`

> buildscript {
>       repositories {
>           mavenCentral()
>       }
>       dependencies {
>           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
>       } }

I am not sure how to fix this problem, any suggestion is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you have the wrong version. Try to change 4.0 to 3.3 to download the jar via Maven Central. Or download the jar from http://forge.ow2.org/projects/asm/ and install in to your local maven repository with mvn install:install-file -Dfile=FILENAME.jar -DgroupId=GROUP_ID -DartifactId=ARTIFACT_ID -Dversion=4.0 -Dpackaging=jar

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick reply. But what am I suppose to replace in the GROUP_ID and ARTIFACT_ID?

Comment: Basically anything you like. But i´d insert the original identifiers as described here http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=asm/asm-analysis/3.3/asm-analysis-3.3.pom
Remember to change the version to 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same problem, ow2.org has separate repository

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repository.ow2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
```